# Undefined Reference to `vc_gencmd(char *, int, char const *, ...)`

Tags: raspbian-stretch, raspicam, video, mmal

I wanted to control the raspberry pi camera with MMAL and I used the [RaspiCamControl.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiCamControl.c) file to learn how to control the camera component then
I wrote a class about it. I've created and added all the functions that I needed. In this file ([RaspiCamControl.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiCamControl.c)), there are two function calls at the lines between 1741 to 1766 from `interface/vmcs_host/vc_vchi_gencmd.h` which are `vc_gencmd(char *, int, char const *, ...)` and `vc_gencmd_number_property(char *, char const *, int *)`. I can see their declaration at the `vc_vchi_gencmd.h` file but when I want to build, Qt is giving errors about these functions references are undefined.

Here is my pro file;

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/orkun/rpi/sysroot/opt/vc/include \
           /home/orkun/rpi/sysroot/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host \
           /home/orkun/rpi/sysroot/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads \
           /home/orkun/rpi/sysroot/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux

LIBS += -L/home/orkun/rpi/sysroot/opt/vc/lib

LIBS += -lbcm_host
LIBS += -lbrcmEGL
LIBS += -lbrcmGLESv2
LIBS += -lbrcmOpenVG
LIBS += -lbrcmWFC
LIBS += -lcontainers
LIBS += -ldebug_sym
LIBS += -ldebug_sym_static
LIBS += -ldtovl
LIBS += -lEGL
LIBS += -lEGL_static
LIBS += -lelftoolchain
LIBS += -lGLESv1_CM
LIBS += -lGLESv2
LIBS += -lGLESv2_static
LIBS += -lkhrn_client
LIBS += -lkhrn_static
LIBS += -lmmal
LIBS += -lmmal_components
LIBS += -lmmal_core
LIBS += -lmmal_util
LIBS += -lmmal_vc_client
LIBS += -lopenmaxil
LIBS += -lOpenVG
LIBS += -lvcfiled_check
LIBS += -lvchiq_arm
LIBS += -lvchostif
LIBS += -lvcilcs
LIBS += -lvcsm
LIBS += -lvcos
LIBS += -lWFC

LIBS += -pthread
```

These are all the libraries (except `pthread`) at the `/opt/vc/libs` folder. I'm searched about the error but found nothing on the google.
I'm a bit confused, should I implement these functions? Or, is there any other library at somewhere else?

Thanks. Sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT:** The error disappears when include the related file with;

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "interface/vmcs_host/vc_vchi_gencmd.h"
}
```

I don't know this is the right way to that but error is gone now.
Should I delete the question?

Comment: No, don't delete the question. Make an answer and accept it after some days. Then others may find your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined reference errors have gone when include the `vc_vchi_gencmd.h` file with `extern "C"...` declaration;

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "interface/vmcs_host/vc_vchi_gencmd.h"
}
```